# Can't load antigen in zsh - my source command always gets an extra "/bin" appended

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to load antigen - the zsh plugin manager. No matter how I try to source it - copying it to /usr/bin/zsh/plugins or just in my home dir, it always fails due to the terminal always adding an unwanted /bin to whatever source command I enter into .zshrc.

This is the error message:

```
/home/kronos/.antigen/antigen.zsh:source:2: no such file or directory: /home/kronos/.antigen/bin/antigen.zsh
```

This is the .zshrc line concerning sourcing antigen:

```
kronos@void ~/configuration a:% cat .zshrc.test | grep antigen           
source /home/kronos/.antigen/antigen.zsh
```

I noticed when echo $PATH that it looks as follows:

```
kronos@void ~ % echo $PATH
/home/kronos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

So I assume that the ~/bin line is the culprit here? I don't know where it came from, I didn't add it. How do I remove it?

Comment: The error is coming from inside `/home/kronos/.antigen/antigen.zsh`, seems like. Check what's in it.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is not from your `zshrc`, but from `/home/kronos/.antigen/antigen.zsh`.  From the [antigen page](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen), it looks like you are meant to install it by copying the entire repository.

Then you should have `source /path-to-antigen/antigen.zsh` in your `zshrc`, which it appears you do. On the [second line of this file](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/blob/develop/antigen.zsh#L2) that is sourced, another file is sourced, `/path-to-antigen/bin/antigen.zsh`, which appears to be missing in your install. Make sure that you have copied the entire repository, not just that one file.